# Rails 4 - How to create a tenantship relationship between a user and a space?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am building a Rails 4 app and am trying to figure out how to create a relationship between a `User` and `Space` model in the form of `tenantship`.

The `tenantship` model will have: `user_id`, `space_id`, `start_time`, `end_time`

I have tried using `ActiveRecord` Associations to achieve this but my primary problem is when it comes to users actually enrolling in a `tenantship`, how do I go about in my views, controllers, and model recording a user becoming a tenant for a certain period of time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for a `has_many :through` relationship, as you're interested in not just the relationship between Users and Spaces, but also want to tack on some additional details like the term of the tenancy. Now, in more detail:

#### Models

The official docs for a `has_many :through` relationship are here (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

This should give you three models: `Space`, `User`, and `Tenancy`, which look roughly like this:

```
class User
  has_many :spaces, through: :tenancies
end

class Space
  has_many :users, as: :residents, through: :tenancies
end

class Tenancy
  # user_id
  # space_id
  # date_from
  # date_to
  belongs_to :spaces
  belongs_to :users
end
```

#### Controllers

You'll probably want basic controllers both `User` and `Spaces`, which will allow you to create/edit/delete those. The slightly more unusual controller will be `TenancyController`. You'll be able to post to this controller to create new tenancies, e.g.:

```
class TenancyController
  def create
    Tenancy.create(tenancy_params)
    # ...
  end


  private

  def tenancy_params
    params.permit(:user_id, :space_id, :date_from, :date_to)
  end
end
```

#### Views

To correspond with the Tenancy controller, you'll want a view that has inputs for both the User and Space. This might look something like:

```
= form_for Tenancy.new do |f|
  = f.user_id
  = f.space_id
  = f.date_from
  = f.date_to
  = f.submit
```

These are obviously rough outlines above, but hopefully should give you some outline for how to proceed!

Answer (score 0):

At the database level, the enrolling of a user in a tenantship of a space is just the creation of a new record in your tenantship table. You record the ids of user and space and save this record. A dedicated controller would be responsible for managing these tenantships. Linking these to the other models requires setting the associations and querying them (finding all users for a certain space, etc.).